# How to make the AC current coming from the wall the backup for a battery powered circuit

Tags: batteries, ac, circuit-design

I want to design a circuit where its main power supply is a battery. I want this circuit to be connected also to AC current coming from the wall. Assume that the power supplies a light bulb where i can modify the intensity of the light. Now the battery has a maximum amount of power that it can deliver. I want to use the AC current as a backup for this battery when the bulb is trying to get more power than the battery can provide or when the battery dies out.
Please keep in mind that the battery cannot in any way send power to the wall and the AC current cannot be allowed to send power to the light bulb without passing the previously mentioned conditions.
I've googled this for a while but unfortunately all i could find was curcuits for a battery as a backup for when the AC current goes out completely.
Thanks.

Comment: first, please post the circuit you found where the batterie is the backup and second, have a look into rectifiers. And why use AC as backup? are you experiencing voltage losses at home?
Also, specifiy voltage levels, maximum current, minimum current and so on.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what use-case do you have where you don't want the mains power to have priority?

Comment: How do you keep the battery charged so that it can be your "primary" source?  Your scheme actually makes no sense. Unless there is some unusual circumstances that you have not revealed. The reason that you can find only circuits where the battery is a trickle-charged, "floating" back-up supply when the mains fail is because that is the only use-case that actually makes any sense.

Comment: In your opening line you say "I want to design a circuit....". Given this requirement, what is your specific question?

Comment: @RichardCrowley let's just say that the battery can be charged from another source

Comment: @Andyaka my question is how to design such a circuit

Comment: Ah, how to design... are you a qualified EE? Have you any design experience? Have you done anything similar or are you an absolute beginner. If you are a beginner then teaching you how to design circuits is massively beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @Andyaka i am not a qualified EE but I took a couple of circuits courses in college so I am not an absolute beginner either. I have designed simple circuits before but this is just a project i am working on

Comment: The trouble is that you have an indeterminate level of understanding and asking "how to design" is difficult because nobody really knows where your main skills lie that an answer could exploit.

Comment: @Andyaka well you might have a point there non the less I'll be showing all the answers to a friend of mine who's studying electric engineering ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give enough detail in your question about any 'smarts' the changeover system should employ, so I'm assuming that it's simply exhaustion of the battery causing its voltage to drop that should make the changeover.

Consider the simple circuit below. Two power supplies have different voltages, and are connected by diodes. The higher voltage supply will feed the load, no current will be drawn from the lower voltage supply.

Note that in this crude switch, the load voltage will be roughly 0.7v less than the serving supply.

You don't give any detail of the currents to be used, so I'm going to leave the schematic with the default 1N4148's that are OK to 10s of mA. If you want 2A, then you'll need something like 1N540x diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk9zZc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say you want to protect a 4 cell NimH battery from exhaustion, and you'd like to be supporting it at 1.1v per cell, so at 4.4v on the battery. Your wall power supply should drive a regulator with an output of 4.4v.

At the nominal battery output of 4.8v, all the supply will come from the battery, and this will still be the case when the battery voltage has dropped to 4.5v on load. At 4.4v output, 50% of the supply will come from battery, and 50% from the wall. By the time the battery gets to 4.3v, all of the current will be supplied from the wall.

Of course if one supply disappears totally, then the other supply will pick up. This is *usually* the wall supply going, with the backup battery picking up, the type of diagrams you've been finding in your search.

Comment: I'd reccomend 1N4001 diodes (or other rectifier diodes), IN4148 is only good for about 100mA

Comment: So if I understand correctly the wall power will still be used. But is there a way to prevent the wall power completely as long as the battery is still in use. Also please consider that both the battery and the AC current both have the same voltage. Excuse my lack of knowledge of some technicalities in circuits

Comment: As long as the battery voltage is 100mV above the wall power regulated voltage, the battery will supply all the current. If the battery doesn't change voltage, how will you know when the battery is discharged? The battery only needs to change voltage by 200mV between supplying the current, and not supplying the current. Any defect in my solution is completely down to your lack of detail in the question.

Comment: @omarwaleed You would need to drop the voltage from the AC supply, even if only slightly, so that it is below the voltage of a healthy battery.